# List all available model attributes in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

For debugging purposes I would like to list **all** model attributes available to my thymeleaf template while it is rendering.

Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="model : ${*}">
        <td th:text="${model}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But obviously that's nonsense, and I get a well-deserved error.
(`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1070E:(pos 0): Problem parsing left operand`)

Is there a way of outputting such debug information?  I'd settle even for some logging output.

Or, does Thymeleaf provide something similar to Struts 2's `struts.devMode` where it added a debug section at the bottom of the page listing all available properties?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="var : ${#vars}">
        <td th:text="${var.key}"></td>
        <td th:text="${var.value}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fantastic - this actually gives even more than I wanted: includes all of the spring beans available to the views, not just the models I've put in. Very useful information!

Comment: @the4dK you are a life saver!

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer does not seem to work for Thymeleaf 3; here's an update.  Please note that I'm using Spring; this might not work for non-Spring apps.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="var : ${#vars.getVariableNames()}">
        <td th:text="${var}"></td>
        <td th:text="${#vars.getVariable(var)}"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 
        Adding these manually because they are considered special.
        see https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/thymeleaf-3.0.3.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/context/WebEngineContext.java#L199
    -->
    <tr>
        <td>param</td>
        <td th:text="${#vars.getVariable('param')}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>session</td>
        <td th:text="${#vars.getVariable('session')}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>application</td>
        <td th:text="${#vars.getVariable('application')}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That said, what I've done is created a standalone Bean that makes things a bit prettier and dumps to logs instead of to HTML:

```
@Component
public class ThymeleafDumper {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThymeleafDumper.class);

    public void dumpToLog(WebEngineContext ctx) {
        log.debug("Thymeleaf context: {}", formatThisUpNicely(ctx));
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

Where `formatThisUpNicely` can use `ctx.getVariableNames()`, put the results into a `SortedMap`, export to `json`, whatever.  Don't forget those three 'special' variables!

Then expose an instance of it as a `@ModelAttribute` in a `Controller` or a `ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeControllerAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private ThymeleafDumper thymeleafDumper;

    @ModelAttribute("dumper")
    public ThymeleafDumper dumper() {
        return this.thymeleafDumper;
    }
}
```

Then in my template run:

```
<div th:text="${dumper.dumpToLog(#vars)}"/>
```

Comment: Roy, I would have never, never, never figured out

Comment: Roy, I would have never, never, never figured out mav.addObject(Company.getCompany()) would become "string" displaying Tear Drop on the view even though it told me right here: In CompanyController.java mav model is {string=Tear Drop}. I can't wait to define some more fields. I bet they will be "string1...", at least until I figure out what I am supposed to be doing. Thank you so much 3 years later! ==> comments can only be edited for so many minutes. I had better learn to type faster.

Answer (score 5):

these are all the logging available configurations :

```
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.TIMER=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.cache.TEMPLATE_CACHE=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.cache.FRAGMENT_CACHE=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.cache.MESSAGE_CACHE=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.cache.EXPRESSION_CACHE=DEBUG
```

these will log all the thymeleaf actions. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: But beware, spring boot users!  http://izeye.blogspot.com/2015/02/enable-orgthymeleaf-trace-log-in-spring.html

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf 3.0:
To put it short, try the following:

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="var : ${param.keySet()}">
    <td th:text="${var}"></td>
    <td th:text="${param.get(var)}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When a `@Controller` returns some value stored in a Spring `Model`, the values are actually stored as request parameters, which is accessible using:
`request.getParameter("paramName");`
Thymeleaf provides a similar functionality: "Web context namespaces for request/session attributes", the syntax is as stated.

The Thymeleaf built-in `${param}` kewords returns an  `WebRequestParamsVariablesMap extends VariablesMap<String,String[]>` object,
whose keySet() method returns a `String[]`, which contains those variable names within a `httprequest`.

Comment: This is just outputting a blank table for me.