# SpringTemplateEngine.process doesn't read file (thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, template-engine

I'm trying to use a Thymeleaf template engine to create an html email, by following [this tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-thymeleaf-html-template-example/).

I've created the template configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;


@Configuration
public class ThymeleafTemplateConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver(){
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return templateResolver;
  }
}
```

and an html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is the body to be changed</p>
  <p>This is a name: ${name}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I try to populate the template:

```
templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("name", "my name");

String html = templateEngine.process("index", context);
System.out.println(html);
```

But rather than getting the populated template, I'm just getting the first parameter I put into process:

```
>>> my name
```

What am I doing wrong? why does process take the parameter as-is rather than reading the file with the specified prefix and suffix? (/templates/index.html)

Comment: can you post the full directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the example you mention a bean called `SpringTemplateEngine` is being created and the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` is being injected into it.

Your code does not make any use of the created `bean`. Instead it creates an new instance of `SpringTemplateEngine`. My guess, this new instance does not know SpringResourceTemplateResolver.

Two possible fixes

1. Autowired the bean instead of creating new instance
2. Create this instance the same way you create the `bean`, i.e `addTemplateResolver` to the new instance

Comment: You're right, I Autowired it and now it does read the template file. It still doesn't replace ${name} with the name variable from the context though

Comment: @shayelk it may be helpful to print all the known vars to the template. For doing that check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387526/list-all-available-model-attributes-in-thymeleaf

Comment: The problem was actually the inline mechanism. it turns out you should use [[${name}]] rather than ${name} as per Thymeleaf doc: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html